# Не работает метод CONNECT

Tags: http

Здравствуйте. Пытаюсь в учебных целях написать прокси сервер. Столкнулся с проблемой  в самом начале. Сайты не отвечают мне когда я посылаю им запрос на установление ssl соединения через прокси.

```
CONNECT google.com:443 HTTP/1.1\r\n\r\n
```

Пытался отправлять этот запрос через fiddler. Результат тот же. Не могу понять что я делаю не так.

Comment: Сайты это просто как пример.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Все правильно, SSL/TLS протокол устроен так, что при соединении первым посылает данные клиент (сообщение ClientHello). Сервер просто держит соединение открытым и ожидает данные.

Comment: Вот оно что) Спасибо Вам огромное)

Comment: Хотя если честно все равно не совсем понятно. Вот я в настройках firefox прописал свой прокси сервер. Браузер отправляет connect, но больше никаких данных не отправляет. Не могу понять. Чего он ждет, если вдогонку он должен начать рукопожатие?

Comment: Странно, возможно проблема в чем-то другом. А если без TLS, прокси работает?

Comment: Да. http прокси работает хорошо.

Comment: Возможно проблема в том, что прокси не отвечает браузеру на connect ответом HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n\r\n?

Comment: Похоже что да. В этом RFC пишется, что нужен 2хх ответ: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2817#section-5.2

Comment: Да. Действительно. Так и получилось) Спасибо еще раз Вам огромное)